# Recover funds knowing passphrase, receiving address and seed

Tags: wallet-recovery

Doing tests with a coldcard I probably made a mess with derivation paths and the exporting of public key.

When I did a test transaction I could not recover my funds right after. It's a very little amount (11 $ ~)  but I would like to understand how to recover them.

I know the 24 seed words and the bip39 passphrase (I actually have 2 possible versions of this) and I have the receiving address I sent the funds.

What can I do to revover my funds?

Comment: Do you have a spare coldcard and have you read the backup section at https://coldcard.com/docs/advanced/